# Convert Excel spreadsheet to XML with attributes

Tags: c#, excel, xml

I have an Excel spreadsheet that is full of part numbers and components which belong to that part number.  I'd like to convert this to XML for a program I'm redesigning.  Below is how the columns in the Excel file are laid out:

Product Part number | PCA | Reference Designator | Item Number | Location

I'd like to format the XML file to show like the following:

```
<Product_Part_Number>
  <PCA_1>
    <Part>
      <RefDes>Z001</RefDes>
      <ItemNum>1234567</ItemNum>
      <Location>Bin 1</Location>
    </Part>
  </PCA_1>
  <PCA_2>
    <Part>
      <RefDes>R001</RefDes>
      <ItemNum>987654</ItemNum>
      <Location>Bin 30</Location>
    </Part>
  </PCA_2>
</Product_Part_Number>
```

Is there a way I can read in a column at a time, add the PCA level, then the RefDes level, etc?  I'm thinking it would require a couple of loops but was curious if someone has already done this before.

Comment: I would oledb connection and a adapter to return query to a datatable.  Then loop through rows of datatable and create the xml.  I like using xml linq to create the xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You can export the xml file to CSV format, then it would be easy to [process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-generate-xml-from-csv-files) in C# code.